# Gaps between arrows and labels

Tags: arrows, xy-pic

I have a question about my diagram. How can I increase the gap between the arrows and the labels? I would like to have more space between the left arrow and the label (2). Thanks for any suggestions.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[all]{xypic}

\begin{document}
     \begin{equation*}
    \begin{gathered}
    \quad
        \SelectTips{cm}{} \xymatrix@C=4.5em@R=4.5em{ A
       \ar@<-1ex>@{=>}[d] _-{(3)}\ar@<1ex>@{=>}[r]^-{(1)}  & B  
            \ar@<1ex>@{=>}|{{\object@{/}}}[l]^-{(2)}         \\
         C         \ar@<1ex>@{=>}[r] \ar@<-1ex>@{=>}[u] |{\object@{/}}|{}_-{\;(4)}   & D 
     \ar@<1ex>@{=>}[l] \ar@<-1ex>@{=>}[u]_{\;(5)} }
     \end{gathered}
     \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I don't find it tedious, just forgot adding the commands you mentioned. I have recently edited my code. It is now compilable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. You can modify the spacing of labels globally by adding `@L=dimen` after `\xymatrix`. In this case remove all additional spaces like `\;` you've inserted in the code. For example:

   ```
   \documentclass{amsart}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage[all]{xy}

   \begin{document}
        \begin{equation*}
        \quad
           \SelectTips{cm}{} \xymatrix@L=6pt@C=4.5em@R=4.5em{ A
          \ar@<-1ex>@{=>}[d] _-{(3)}\ar@<1ex>@{=>}[r]^-{(1)}  & B
               \ar@<1ex>@{=>}|{{\object@{/}}}[l]^-{(2)}         \\
            C         \ar@<1ex>@{=>}[r] \ar@<-1ex>@{=>}[u] |{\object@{/}}|{}_-{(4)}   & D
        \ar@<1ex>@{=>}[l] \ar@<-1ex>@{=>}[u]_{(5)} }
        \end{equation*}
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]
2. You can modify the spacing of the single label treating it as an object, that is to say replace `^{...}` with `^*modifiers{...}`. In your case you will need the modifier `+<dimen>`, so replace `^-{(2)}` with something like `^*+<1em>{^{(2)}}` and adjust `1em` to your needs. For example:

   ```
   \documentclass{amsart}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage[all]{xy}

   \begin{document}
        \begin{equation*}
        \quad
           \SelectTips{cm}{} \xymatrix@C=4.5em@R=4.5em{ A
          \ar@<-1ex>@{=>}[d] _-{(3)}\ar@<1ex>@{=>}[r]^-{(1)}  & B
               \ar@<1ex>@{=>}|{{\object@{/}}}[l]^*+<1em>{^{(2)}}         \\
            C         \ar@<1ex>@{=>}[r] \ar@<-1ex>@{=>}[u] |{\object@{/}}|{}_-{\;(4)}   & D
        \ar@<1ex>@{=>}[l] \ar@<-1ex>@{=>}[u]_-{\;(5)} }
        \end{equation*}
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

Answer (score 2):

They key `@L=dimen` can be used to change the default margin for labels (see [here](http://tex.loria.fr/graph-pack/doc-xypic/xyguide-html/node24.html)). Taking out the spaces that you've manually added and adding `@L=1.25ex` roughly achieves the result that you want, I believe.

You can change the dimension as necessary, however.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[all]{xypic}

\begin{document}
     \begin{equation*}
    \begin{gathered}
    \quad
        \SelectTips{cm}{} \xymatrix@C=4.5em@R=4.5em@L=1.25ex{ A
       \ar@<-1ex>@{=>}[d] _-{(3)}\ar@<1ex>@{=>}[r]^-{(1)}  & B  
            \ar@<1ex>@{=>}|{{\object@{/}}}[l]^{(2)}         \\
         C         \ar@<1ex>@{=>}[r] \ar@<-1ex>@{=>}[u] |{\object@{/}}|{}_-{(4)}   & D 
     \ar@<1ex>@{=>}[l] \ar@<-1ex>@{=>}[u]_{(5)} }
     \end{gathered}
     \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about another approach via `Tikz-cd`? It looks promising.

The arrow distance can be changed via `xshift=<dim>` and `yshift=<dim>`.

The node clearance can be changed via `inner sep=<dim>`.

The label distance can be changed via `node [above, below, right, left=<dim>]{label}`.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
%\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=3cm,column sep=3cm,inner sep=3ex]
A   \arrow[thick,Rightarrow,yshift=2ex,]{r}[above=0.5cm]{(1)}        
    \arrow[thick,Leftarrow, xshift=2ex]{d}[description,sloped]{/}[right=0.5cm]{(4)} 
& B \arrow[thick,Rightarrow,yshift=-2ex]{l}[below=0.5cm]{(2)}[description]{/} \\
C   \arrow[thick,Leftarrow, xshift=-2ex]{u}{(3)}   
    \arrow[thick,Leftarrow, yshift=2ex]{r}{}        
& D \arrow[thick,Leftarrow, yshift=-2ex]{l}{}         
    \arrow[thick,Rightarrow,xshift=2ex]{u}[right=0.5cm]{(5)} 
\end{tikzcd}


\end{document}
```